# Input issue with Intelij

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I've been using Intelij IDEA but now the IDE also seems automatically start selecting text when I click into the code window.  Also the right click isn't working at all although I have a menu button on my keyboard that does the same job.

I'm not having this problem with any other program on my laptop and don't know if this is a bug or some mode I've accidentally started.

Does anyone know what's going on?

I've decided to reinstall the OS and I'm still getting the problem, below is the logs that were recorded when it happened, I really don't think there is anything useful there though:

```
2019-10-31 11:34:37,323 [5257033]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 174 ms 
2019-10-31 11:58:15,268 [6674978]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFindSettings took 12 ms, WindowManager took 12 ms 
2019-10-31 11:58:15,343 [6675053]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/lex-man/IdeaProjects/petClinicNew/lex-pet-clinic/lex-pet-clinic' lex-pet-cliniclibraryTable took 12 ms 
2019-10-31 11:58:15,348 [6675058]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 128 ms 
2019-10-31 12:44:12,112 [9431822]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/lex-man/IdeaProjects/petClinicNew/lex-pet-clinic/lex-pet-clinic' lex-pet-cliniclibraryTable took 21 ms 
2019-10-31 12:44:12,117 [9431827]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 130 ms 
2019-10-31 14:02:23,641 [14123351]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,417 [14124127]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /home/lex-man/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,421 [14124131]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-automotive/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,421 [14124131]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,423 [14124133]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,421 [14124131]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,423 [14124133]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear-cn/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,421 [14124131]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,427 [14124137]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,431 [14124141]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,432 [14124142]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,433 [14124143]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:02:24,434 [14124144]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml 
2019-10-31 14:07:17,645 [14417355]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/lex-man/IdeaProjects/petClinicNew/lex-pet-clinic/lex-pet-clinic' lex-pet-cliniclibraryTable took 21 ms 
2019-10-31 14:12:35,624 [14735334]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/lex-man/IdeaProjects/petClinicNew/lex-pet-clinic/lex-pet-clinic' lex-pet-cliniclibraryTable took 26 ms
```

Comment: Please attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.

Comment: I restarted my machine and the problem went away.  I'll add a log if it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the Android add-on and it seems to have sorted out my problems.